# What is machine id in Pi. Can we update it to some other id.?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch

I have burned `Raspbian stretch` os image in the card and have installed all the software I need in pi. I have then cloned this same image into other `raspberry pi` devices which I have and thus all 5 `Pi` now have the same `machine id` in them.

Machine id can be accessed using `sudo cat /etc/machine-id`. The python script which run inside the `pi` uses the machine id. If its same in all the devices then its going to create problem.

Can I update the machine id and change it some other unique id. What exactly is the machine id and how can I change it.? Thanks

Comment: Why not try using the processor ID instead so it's tied to the hardware? Something like `awk -F: '/Serial/{print $2}' /proc/cpuinfo` or `awk -F: '/Serial/{print $2}' /proc/cpuinfo | md5sum` should get you started...

Comment: `What exactly is the machine id` .... try using manual pages in linux `man machine-id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *machine-id* is just generated on next boot if the file `/etc/machine-id` is empty. So simple do:

```
rpi ~$ sudo rm /etc/machine-id
rpi ~$ sudo touch /etc/machine-id
```

and reboot.